# Sending an e-mail via wp_mail() by submitted Formik form in React

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, formik

So as the title states above, I am wondering how to achieve this.
Is there a way to pass the submitted Formik values to a WPMAIL file and with those received props send it through to the `wp_mail()` function. And so on, send the props as e-mail to a designated e-mail address. I have found little to no answer to my case and from what I've found, it didn't really help me in any way.

Some say you have to register the rest route, in my case /contact, but that didn't help me.

Currently I have to following in my ContactScreen.js:

```
<div className="w-full">
 <div className="mx-4 rounded-lg">
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ name: '', email: '', phone: '', message: '',}}
    validationSchema={SignupSchema}
    onSubmit={(values, {resetForm}) => {
      this.setState({values: values})
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.values, null, 2));
      resetForm({ values: '' })
    }}
    >
    {({ errors, touched }) => (
      <FormikForm className="bg-lightorange rounded pt-8 pb-16 px-20 mb-4 " method="POST">
        <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-2">
          <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
            <div className={`${errors.name && touched.name ? 'display-block invalid-message' : 'display-none'} rounded h-8 mb-2 text-xs ease-in-out duration-300`}><ErrorMessage name="name"/></div>
            <FormikField placeholder="Naam" type="text" name="name" className={`appearance-none block w-full active:bg-white-100 rounded my-2 py-3 px-8 leading-10 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white ${errors.name && touched.name ? 'invalid' : null}`} />
          </div>
          <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
            <div className={`${errors.email && touched.email ? 'display-block invalid-message' : 'display-none'} rounded h-8 mb-2 text-xs ease-in-out duration-300`}><ErrorMessage name="email"/></div>
            <FormikField placeholder="E-mailadres" type="email" name="email" className={`appearance-none block w-full active:bg-white-100 rounded my-2 py-3 px-8 leading-10 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white ${errors.email && touched.email ? 'invalid' : null}`} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 px-3 my-2">
          <div className="w-full">
            <div className={`${errors.phone && touched.phone ? 'display-block invalid-message' : 'display-none'} rounded h-8 mb-2 text-xs ease-in-out duration-300`}><ErrorMessage name="phone"/></div>
            <FormikField placeholder="Telefoonnummer" type="text" name="phone" maxLength="12" className={`appearance-none block w-full active:bg-white-100 rounded my-2 py-3 px-8 leading-10 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white ${errors.phone && touched.phone ? 'invalid' : null}`}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 px-3 my-2">
          <div className="w-full">
            <div className={`${errors.message && touched.message ? 'display-block invalid-message' : 'display-none'} rounded h-8 mb-2 text-xs ease-in-out duration-300`}><ErrorMessage name="message"/></div>
            <FormikField placeholder="Bericht" as="textarea" name="message" rows={4} className={`appearance-none block w-full resize-none active:bg-white-100 rounded my-2 py-3 px-8 leading-10 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white ${errors.message && touched.message ? 'invalid' : null}`}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
          <Button type="submit">Bericht versturen</Button>
        </div>
      </FormikForm>
    )}
  </Formik>
</div>
```

And this is in my ContactMailApi.php (which on the same level as the `src` folder:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);

if (empty($_POST['name']) && empty($_POST['email'])) die();

if ($_POST) {
 http_response_code(200);
 $to = "example@gmail.com";
 $subject = $_POST['name'];
 $from = $_POST['email'];

 $msg = $_POST['number'] . $_POST['message'];

 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
 $headers.= "From: <" . $from . ">";
 wp_mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);


 echojson_encode(array(
  "sent" => true
 ));
}
else {
 echojson_encode(["sent" => false, "message" => "Something went wrong"]);
}
```

How am I able to accomplish this? Or am I totally overlooking something fairly easy?
If more detailed info is needed, let me know below

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind this now. I just axios post'ed it to a new registered rest_api route. And from there fetched that url with the response...